# Bromate ion point group?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry

Would the bromate ion have C3v point group due to the trigonal pyramidal geometry? I see a C3 rotational axis and a vertical plane of symmetry. Am I missing anything in terms of the double bonds or are those the only symmetry operations in this molecule?

Comment: As its not planar it should be should be C3v, the double /single are just a representation of bonding.